# how to sort NSMangedObjects by its NSDate attributes

Tags: sorting, nsdate, nsmanagedobject

Question is short:

I have an array of some NSManagedObjects,

all of them have an NSDate attribute

Now I want to sort this arry by their date, the latest the first,

how could implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use NSArray's `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method with an NSSortDescriptor. If your array is called `array` and the NSDate attribute is called `date`, then this would work:

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Also, note that when you're getting these NSManagedObjects using an NSFetchRequest, you can give the request sortDescriptors so that they're already sorted. Using the same `sortDescriptors` from above, just do the following before executing the request:

```
request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
```